# Vector/Processing ToolBar not available QGIS 3.4/ Mac OSx 10.13.6

Tags: qgis

When I installed QGIS, I performed the bug fix as directed (going into the Environment section, adding a variable, etc), and restarted both the program and eventually my computer, but there is still no Vector or Processing toolbox available. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the program.  Any other ideas? We have to use this version for the class I'm taking.

Comment: "the bug fix" - ah, that one... or the other one? Which one exactly, please?

Comment: This:A workaround is to use QGIS custom variables.  Open QGIS Preferences → System.

- Under the Environment section, turn on Use Custom Variables.
- Add (+) a variable
- Select Prepend from the Apply popup
- Enter PATH for the variable
- For the Value enter:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/Programs:
- Quit QGIS 3 and start it again